# SQL - Similarity between two strings of varying length

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, algorithm, clr, similarity

I have a SQL Server table of products, and each product has a description that is publicly available on our website. I want to prevent, or at least warn our users when, a description is too similar to another product's description. Each product's description length can greatly vary.

I'd like query for products with descriptions that include duplicate/similar paragraphs/blocks of text between one another. i.e. String A has a bunch of unique content, but shares a similar/identical paragraph w/ string B. However, I'm not sure which similarity algorithm is best to use:

- The [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) and [Jaro-Winler distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance) algorithms appear to only work well with short strings.
- I'm not sure the [longest common subsequence algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) takes into account large differences very well. i.e. it appears to ignore potential space between two characters, finding any similar combination sequence.

[Fuzzy hashing](http://www.technologyreview.com/view/423446/the-unexpected-ubiquity-of-spam-detection-algorithms/) sort of sounds what I'm looking for, but I'm *not just* looking for duplicate content w/ subtle differences. I'm *also* looking for duplicate content w/ subtle differences injected **within a unique block of text**. And I'd have no idea how to implement fuzzy hashes in SQL. [SOUNDEX()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx) and [DIFFERENCE()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188753.aspx) appear to use fuzzy hashing, but are quite imprecise for my use case.

Ideally the similarity SQL function would be fast, but I could store cached similarity values in another table and schedule a job to occasionally update.

**What is the best algorithm/SQL (or CLR integration) implementation to accomplish this?**

Comment: Why are you limiting yourself to implementing this in SQL?

Comment: Well, I suppose it doesn't need to be in SQL. However, I'm assuming a pure SQL implementation will be more performant. I could potentially use a .NET CLR integration like [this similarity library](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2011/02/05/finding-similar-strings-with-fuzzy-logic-functions-built-into-mds/)... but I have no experience with SQL Server CLR integration and I still wouldn't know what algorithm to use.

Comment: One thing you could try is to take the string and only consider instances of certain letters, then Levenshtein those strings. For example, take a text like "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" and only consider instances of e's and t's. The resultant string would be etet, which you could Levenshtein against another filtered string. Obviously requires some tuning, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: @kevmo314 Interesting. I assume the purpose of cutting out a significant portion of the alphabet, is to aid matches on single paragraph matches?

Comment: @DavidBudiac Sorta. The general idea is that because Levenshtein is O(n^2), cutting out 75% of n yields a 94% improvement in performance, and we want to take advantage of that. We also know that a lot of times, you can interpolate words even if characters are missing, so by cutting out characters, we're kind of generating a compressed version that's more like a signature of the text than deflate-esque compression. This also abuses the fact that we don't ever need to "decompress" the signature. :)

Comment: I had a similar issue that I was able to use the new STRING_SPLIT() function for in SQL 2016, and then compared the number of words that were repeated in the body of a field on one record compared to others. Was fairly complicated, and wouldn't perform well at large scale, but gave me the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I not-so-recently had to join group names by fuzzy string matching.
I have tried about 40 different algorithms, but none was good enough to do this,even though the groupnames writing only differed by some spelling mistakes, missing whitespaces, and occasional added _mLF at the end.

So if you attempt a similar thing, I strongly suggest you stop right now, and send the data (in my case Excel-file) back to the users for correction, where it belongs.

If you're really just interested in comparing strings, this link may be just what you need:
http://anastasiosyal.com/POST/2009/01/11/18.ASPX

I found the Jaro-Winkler function to yield the best results in my case, but you can test that for yourselfs.

Comment: Yeah, ideally I'd tell the users to stop inputing duplicate text. But some will continue to do it anyway... I need to be able to retroactively discover when content is duplicated/similar. That article definitely helps.

Comment: I've also found this fuzzy search algorithm to be reasonably performant: https://sites.google.com/site/sqlblindman/fuzzysearchalgorithm