# Improve TSQL brute-force similarity query

Tags: t-sql, optimization, nlp, similarity

I need to allocate parts to individual groups. The groups each have various text strings that show their areas of responsibilities. The parts to check are also identified by their own text strings. Currently I am doing a brute force similarity check for each part against each group and returning the best similarity score. This works but is very slow, of course.

I'd appreciate any different ways of looking at this. The text strings in both tables are just words and I don't see a good way to organize these before doing the check in a way that would minimize the number of times I have to run through the similarity code.

Here's an example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Parts') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Parts

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DetailsTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #DetailsTable

CREATE TABLE #Parts(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PG] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ML] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](80) NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE #DetailsTable(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](80) NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO #Parts(PG, ML, Description)
VALUES
('PA','001','Suspension-Leveling Sensor'),
('PA','001','Control Arm Bumper'),
('PB','002','Active Suspension'),
('PB','002','Air Suspension Ride Height Sensor'),
('PB','002','Suspension Control Arm and Ball Joint Assembly'),
('PC','003','Air Suspension Line Repair Kit'),
('PC','003','Electronic Air Suspension Compressor');
INSERT INTO #DetailsTable(Description)
VALUES
('ABSORBER-SUSPENSION'),
('STRUT-FRONTSUSPENSION'),
('STRUT-SUSPENSION'),
('ABSBR KIT-SUSPENSION'),
('ABSORBER-SUSPENSION'),
('AIR SUSPENSION STRUT'),
('BUSHING-SUSPENSION'),
('C/MEMBER-FRONT SUSPENSION'),
('KNUCKLE-SUSPENSION'),
('BALL-JOINT'),
('CONTROL-BUMPER')
;

DECLARE @iRow INT, @iRowRR INT, @count INT, @countRR INT;
DECLARE @tempStringML varchar(50), @tempStringPG varchar(50), @tempStringDescription varchar(50), @hiTempStringML varchar(50),
    @hiTempStringPG varchar(50), @hiTempDescription varchar(50),
    @Details varchar(500), @hiDetails varchar(500);
DECLARE @Jaccard FLOAT, @hiJaccard FLOAT;

SET @iRow = 1;
SET @iRowRR = 1;
SET @countRR = (SELECT count(#DetailsTable.Id) FROM #DetailsTable);
SET @count = (SELECT count(#Parts.Id) FROM #Parts);


WHILE @iRowRR <= @countRR
BEGIN
    SET @Details = (SELECT #DetailsTable.Description FROM #DetailsTable WHERE #DetailsTable.Id = @iRowRR);
    SET @iRow = 1;
    SET @hiJaccard = 0
    WHILE @iRow <= @count
        BEGIN
            /*establish loop structure*/
            SET @tempStringML = (SELECT #Parts.ML FROM #Parts WHERE #Parts.Id = @iRow);
            SET @tempStringDescription = (SELECT #Parts.Description FROM #Parts WHERE #Parts.Id = @iRow);
            SET @tempStringPG = (SELECT #Parts.PG FROM #Parts WHERE #Parts.Id = @iRow);
            SET @Jaccard = mdsdb.mdq.similarity(@Details,@tempStringDescription, 1, 0.85,0)
            IF(@Jaccard > @hiJaccard)
            BEGIN
                SET @hiJaccard = @Jaccard
                SET @hiTempDescription = @tempStringDescription
                SET @hiTempStringML = @tempStringML
                SET @hiTempStringPG = @tempStringPG
                SET @hiDetails = @Details
            END
            SET @iRow = @iRow + 1
        END;
    PRINT @hiTempStringPG + ' ' + @hiTempStringML + ' ' + @hiTempDescription + ' ' + @hiDetails + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar, @hiJaccard);
    SET @iRowRR = @iRowRR + 1;
END
```

Update 20160220:

My processing window was just under 60 hours (15,000 strings going up against 70,000 strings) and that wasn't going to work. I went a different direction and added start/stop outside variables, temp'd all the working tables and wrote the results to a common output table. I did some additional work outside the similarity loop to lighten the load and ran multiple instances from a sqlcmd script.

I became CPU bound just as I was running out of memory at 7 instances and got a 6.4x speed-up.

```
@echo off
echo Do you want to delete RegResultsTeam?
set /p INPUT=""
cls
echo %INPUT%
If /I "%INPUT%"=="y" goto yes
If /I "%INPUT%"=="n" goto no
:yes
sqlcmd -d Similarity -Q "if exists (select [name] from sys.tables where  [name] = 'RegResultsTeam') DROP table RegResultsTeam"
:no
START sqlcmd  -d Similarity -i .\03-distrib-par.sql -v cycleStart=00001 cycleEnd=10000
START sqlcmd  -d Similarity -i .\03-distrib-par.sql -v cycleStart=10001 cycleEnd=20000
START sqlcmd  -d Similarity -i .\03-distrib-par.sql -v cycleStart=20001 cycleEnd=30000
START sqlcmd  -d Similarity -i .\03-distrib-par.sql -v cycleStart=30001 cycleEnd=40000
START sqlcmd  -d Similarity -i .\03-distrib-par.sql -v cycleStart=40001 cycleEnd=50000
START sqlcmd  -d Similarity -i .\03-distrib-par.sql -v cycleStart=50001 cycleEnd=60000
START sqlcmd  -d Similarity -i .\03-distrib-par.sql -v cycleStart=60001 cycleEnd=69632
```

Thanks for the other suggestions, I appreciate the response.

Pat

Answer (score 0):

Try if below alternate method is faster, but you need to compare the text for each match
[SQL - Similarity between two strings of varying length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624689/sql-similarity-between-two-strings-of-varying-length)